# TypeError: props... is not a function in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get data API from star wars website with react project and here's my code:

```
const Form = (props) => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("people");
  const [searchID, setSearchID] = useState(1);

  const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    buttonAPI();
    setSearch(props.type);
  }, [props.type]);

  const buttonAPI = () => {
    axios
      .get(`https://swapi.dev/api/${props.type}/`)
      .then((res) => {
        setResponseData(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigate(`/${search}/${searchID}`);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container" style={pageStyle}>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
  .
  .
  .

)
```

I'm getting this error while trying to add `props.setSearch(props.type);` into `useEffect`

Here is my github for this project:

https://github.com/nathannewyen/reactjs-practice/tree/master/luke-api

Comment: `setSearch` is not passed as a prop to the component, in fact is available to the component due to the `useState()` hook. Just call `setSearch(props.type)` and it should work. Also remember to pass an array in order to run the effect only when a relevant prop or state property is updated: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Comment: Yea I tried your way and just edited my code but some how `props.type` is undefined in my axios

Comment: You actually have to pass the type prop to the `Form` component and make sure is a function. Something like this:  `<Form type={someFunction} />` Just saw below that the comment by @yash addresses the same thing :D

Answer (score 1):

From your App.jsx:

```js
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Info from "./components/Info";
import Form from "./components/Form";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form />
      <Info />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You pass nothing to `Form` component, so the props is empty and you cannot call a function that not exists.

Comment: How can I pass it into Form components?

Comment: simple :) `<Form type={SOMETHING_YOU_WANT_TO_PASS} />`